# Registration custom field not showing in personal information

Tags: magento2.3

In magento 2.3, I have created custom field(GST number) on registration form. This field's value is saving on DB as. This field's value is showing/editing on admin panel(customer edit). But not showing in customer's account information tab. As i try to update first or last name and click on save button then hey show validation message:

> GST number is required value

.

There is my script:

```
<?php
namespace Test\Customer\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements \Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;
    
    private $eavConfig;
    
    private $attributeResource;
    
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute $attributeResource
    ) {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        $this->attributeResource = $attributeResource;
    }
    
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, "gst_number");

        $attributeSetId = $eavSetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId(Customer::ENTITY);
        $attributeGroupId = $eavSetup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId(Customer::ENTITY);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'gst_number', [
            // Attribute parameters
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'GST number',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => true,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 990,
            'position' => 990,
            'system' => 0,
        ]);
        
        $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'gst_number');
        $attribute->setData('attribute_set_id', $attributeSetId);
        $attribute->setData('attribute_group_id', $attributeGroupId);

        $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', [
            'adminhtml_customer',
            'customer_account_create',
            'customer_account_edit'
        ]);

        $this->attributeResource->save($attribute);
    }
}
?>
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, anybody have can help me into this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to override edit.phtml in your theme or in your module
you can copy from this location and add field according to your need -

```
/magentoroot/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/edit.phtml
```

add this code above checkbox -

```
<div class="field gst required" data-container="change-gst">
            <label class="label" for="gst"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('gst')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text" name="gst" id="gst" autocomplete="gst" data-input="change-gst" value="" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Gst')) ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Please check image too right now i add in my localhost for you.

[image]